# Setting .htcaccess in an external volume for Docker not working

Tags: apache, reactjs, docker, react-router

I have a React webapp using React-Router. I'd like to use pretty URLs, and have [thus opted to use browserHistory for manipulating the URL](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory).

I wanted to use Docker to set up a server and opted for [nimmis/apache-php5](https://hub.docker.com/r/nimmis/apache-php5/%7E/dockerfile/), which I connect to an external volume like this, more or less;

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v ~/externalFolder/:/var/www/html/ nimmis/apache-php5.
```

In order for React-Router's browserHistory to work, I need to set .htaccess like so;

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

I figured if I had this in the root of my external volume all should be good. But it's not working.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: It's `.htaccess`, not `.htcaccess`. Does your file name also have this typo?

Comment: Nope, the typo was only in my post. :P

Answer (score 1):

The docker image I was trying to use was too limited and I'd need to customise it too much(with extra module installs and such), so I simply opted to roll my own docker image instead. I also went with nginx.

Comment: Rolling out your own image, from a suitable base image is also a good solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the potential typo in the `.htaccess` file, make sure to use an absolute path instead of `~` (which should be resolved by the shell as an absolute path, but better be sure and specify it yourself).

From "[Mount a host directory as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)"

> - The `container-dir` must always be an absolute path such as /src/docs.
> - The `host-dir` can either be an absolute path or a name value. If you supply an absolute path for the host-dir, Docker bind-mounts to the path you specify.

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /home/<yourLogin>/externalFolder/:/var/www/html/ nimmis/apache-php5
```

Comment: @RikNieu Then try and `docker exec bash` to it in order to check the content of the `.htaccess` (and its right) from *within* the running container.

Comment: @RikNieu Double-check also the output of `docker logs <yourContainer>` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) to see if there are any clues there.

Comment: I did check the .htaccess in the container and it all looked good. But then I entered a bunch of rubbish into it to see what would happen. Nothing. So I set it to `deny from all`, and still nothing. So I think the docker containers Apache may not be set up to allow for .htaccess rules. I'll try another and report back.

Comment: Exactly: the logical explanation is that the server does not use that configuration file, but depends on another one. The goal now is to find which one.

Comment: Maybe inspecting your image can lead to some clues (http://jerrygamblin.com/2016/06/08/what-to-inspect-when-you-are-inspecting/)

Comment: Thanks VonC, that's a useful link to have!